# How do I clone Ubuntu and Kali Linux (dual boot) from an old internal HDD to a new internal HDD without losing any data?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, clone, kali

I have bought a new internal HDD hard drive as the previous one is old enough now I use Ubuntu and Kali Linux in dual boot and I have done a lot of customization and don't want to do that again with fresh install how do I clone both Kali Linux and Ubuntu as it is now to the new internal HDD without losing any data?

Comment: thanx a lot I have checked but my doubt is do I have to do it os by os like first Ubuntu then Kali or I can do both at the same time

Comment: Clonezilla can clone the whole drive to a new drive of at least the same size (not one single byte smaller).

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: You've tagged an EOL/ESM release so are off-topic, however FYI you can re-install without loosing settings with Ubuntu and official flavors (I don't know about Kali).

Answer (score 0):

Copy the entire drive from one to another. The destination drive needs to be bigger or at least the same size as the source:

Boot into an install cd/usb, "try without installing"

Open gnome-disks or gparted or `sudo fdisk -l`: So you can identify which drive is which.

Open a terminal

`sudo dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/sdY bs=1M status=progress`

**substituting X and Y for the device names you found on your system**
/dev/sd**X** - (the old drive) the entire device, not just a partition(ie sdX1,sdX2).
/dev/sd**Y** - (the new drive) again your writing to the entire device.

Should take a while depending on the size.